# Create an ssl tunnel to allow old device using ssl3 to connect to current server

Tags: ssl

I am having an issue with some devices not being able to connect to vmware horizon after SSLv3 was disabled on the last upgrade.
At the moment there are no firmware upgrades to fix the device so it uses current protocols.

I thought about using a tunnel (such as stunnel) to allow those devices to connect to an intermediate system using SSLv3, and having that system connect to the vmware horizon host, but not sure about how to proceed.

Any experiences on this?